# Hydrostatic pressure direction

Tags: fluid-statics

As well know the hydrostatic pressure has no direction But is this always the case? If for instance, I want to determine the x and y component on a sloped wall, should I then consider the x, and y components of the pressure force or is the same force acting in both directions?

Answer (score 0):

Pressure is a scalar quantity. The stress, i.e. the force per unit surface, produced by pressure on a surface is a vector quantities $\mathbf{t_n}$ that can be written as

$\mathbf{t_n} = - p \mathbf{\hat{n}}$,

being $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$ the unit vector locally orthogonal to the surface and pointing towards the fluid.

If you have an inclined wall that can be described in the first quadrant, as the line connecting $(x_0, 0)$ and $(0, y_0)$, you need to integrate the expression above over the whole line to get the force (per unit length, since we are considering a 2D problem).
If pressure is uniform, you the total force is

$\mathbf{F} = - p \ell \mathbf{\hat{n}} = - p y_0 \mathbf{\hat{x}} - p x_0 \mathbf{\hat{y}}$.

Comment: So I integrated the pressure force along horizontal area and likewise for vertical area ?